# How to generate textures to fit around shapes?

Tags: box2d, textures, libgdx

I have a randomly generated series of EdgeShapes, as shown here:

[image]

My question is, how can I fill that bottom area with a texture in order to make it look like the ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by someone in IRC:

Create a polyon using OpenGL and then map it 1:1 onto the Box2D shape and texture the polygon.

Comment: Hi! I will upvote and share if you could provide an example on this.

Comment: I'm not to sure how to do it myself, but I would create an OpenGL shape at the same time as you create the box2D shape and give it the same variables.

Answer (score -1):

From ancient memory, and looking at the code, this can't be done with edge shapes.  You can chain them together, but even then there is no self-colision, which would allow the shape to overlap itself, and be . . . what?  There are no normals created, nor centroid.

This is just a guess -- it has been a while since I used box2d -- but can you create a polygon instead?  You would first create the N number of points in an array, and use that array as y-values along the top to simulate ground.  Then you would make each point's y-value equal it's neighboring (left or right) point's y-value over time.  As the points reach the end, they are moved off the array, and a new value is moved onto the other end of the array.
Can this be done, and would this adversely affect the contact points with other objects?